# Unable to identify a particular reference in a Java program

Tags: java, class, subclass, superclass, suffix-tree

```
public CompactSuffixTree(SimpleSuffixTree simpleSuffixTree) 
{  
    super(simpleSuffixTree.text);
    super.root = compactNodes(simpleSuffixTree.root, 0);
}
```

The above code is a part of a java implementation of the suffix tree.

Here the `CompactSuffixTree` extends `AbstractSuffixTree` class which has an attribute "text".

The `simpleSuffixTree` class also extends the `AbstractSuffixTree` class.

"root" is an attribute in the `AbstractSuffixTree` class of type `Node` class.

Can anyone please explain what does the code "super(simpleSuffixTree.text);" mean in such a context?

**NOTE: the attribute "text" is not present in the `simpleSuffixTree` class, which is my main point of confusion.strong text**

Comment: `super(simpleSuffixTree.text)` calls the constructor of the superclass with the parameter `simpleSuffixTree.text`. If the variable called `root` is protected, then you can access it as `this.root`, not with `super.root`.

Answer (score 2):

`super(simpleSuffixTree.text);` is a call to the constructor of the super-class `AbstractSuffixTree`. `simpleSuffixTree.text` is passed to the super-class's constructor, and it's probably used to initialize the "text" property of `AbstractSuffixTree`.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the parent constructor is being called. In this case, it'll result in a call to the `AbstractSuffixTree( String text )` function.

Answer (score 0):

**Subclass Constructors** -  `super` keyword to invoke a superclass's constructor, Here is the `CompactSuffixTree` (subclass) constructor that calls the superclass `AbstractSuffixTree` constructor and then initialize root attribute in `AbstractSuffixTree` class.

**this Keyword** -  You can refer to any member of the current object from within an instance method or a constructor by using this. or you can refer super class public or protected members using this keyword, I will recommend you use this keyword instead of `super.root`.